# Dependency between 'security.token_storage' and 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager' Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I have a simple question,

Is there any dependency between:

- `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage` : It's the service that provides Token and Authenticated User
- `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager :` It's the service that allow interracting with relational database

Because when I create a service using those 2 services as injected dependencies, I got a white page and I find in the logs an error (Allowed memory bytes exhausted). And I have enough Memory in my server. So it's rarely that I get a such error, only if I created an infinity loop using dependencies.

But when I remove the EntityManager service from the newly created service, everything works great.

Service config (I want to create a custom TokenStorage without inheritance just to add some additional methods that I need):

```
empire.token_storage:
  class: Empire\UsersBundle\Service\TokenStorage
  arguments:
    - '@security.token_storage'
    - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
  public: true
```

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage as TokenStorageBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

TokenStorage service class:

```
class TokenStorage
{
  public function __construct(TokenStorageBase $token_storage, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function getToken()
  {
    return $this->token_storage->getToken();
  }

  public function getOtherThings()
  {
    //return $other_things;// got from the relational database using $em
  }
}
```

I injected this service '@empire.token_storage' in another service where I needed not only to get the User data from the @security.token_storage, but also to get other things from the database.

This is really strange, I didn't even replaced the @security.token_storage service by the @empire.token_storage service. I have only injected a service in another one.

Can any one have an explication ?

Thank you

Comment: There are no direct dependencies between the two.  You should be developing in development mode.  This will give you actual error pages instead of blank pages.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad for answering. The development mode is enabled and as I said, when it's a problem of infinite loop, the dependencies are loaded until the memory will be exhausted. In the log file there is only this error "Allowed memory bytes exhausted". Even when I try to debug it with setting a breakpoint in the contructor of the Controller or of the empire.token_storage service or the last service in which i'm injecting the empire.token_storage service, I will never get any result and the execution will never reach my breakpoints

Comment: All I can say is that if you are getting a white page then development mode is not enabled.

Comment: Do you see anything more useful when running `bin/console cache:clear` on the command-line?